# MiniDLNA doesn't want to refresh - different version

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, raspbian-buster, headless

Long story short: MiniDLNA installed, manual refreshing via -R does NOT work. But inotify works. Partially. I start MiniDLNA - 0 files. I move all my files from the default location away and move them back instantly - all files indexed. After a restart of MiniDLNA (reboot or systemctl) - 0 files again. Moving also works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MiniDLNA is hardly maintained (last release ~3 years ago) and the solution is just switching the Server Software.

Answer (score 0):

I made an workaround: Adding `(sleep 5; sudo mv /var/lib/minidlna/* /var/cache/minidlna/empty; sudo mv /var/cache/minidlna/empty/* /var/lib/minidlna) &` to the do_start function of /etc/init.d/minidlna. I can atleast use MiniDLNA now - but that is not a proper solution.

Comment: I know this isn't a proper answer, but after I had similar problems, I just installed Serviio on my Pi 4 and and it just works. Serves material (mkv etc) to my 2012 Samsung smart TV, recognises `srt` subtitles, mp3, FLAC, etc. [Guide here](http://blog.themillhousegroup.com/2019/08/serviio-20-on-raspbian-buster.html)

Comment: I would prefer a open source solution. Gerbera fails, incompatible with armv6.

Comment: Are your ownwerships and permissions correct for the folders you are trying to refresh?

Comment: Yes. I already checked that.

Comment: Ah, by the way: Universal Media Server is far too heavy.

Comment: Still no working DLNA Server found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I finally chose MinimServer as replacement - it is lightweight, the browsing is great, it works - it's just not open source.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: It is not answered - that is just an automated way to workaround that issue.

Answer (score 0):

After updating media, renaming directories containing mp3 files followed by force-reload solves problem.

Comment: That is what my workaround does